# Lua Line Wrapping excluding certain characters

Tags: lua, word-wrap

I've located a code that I want to use when I'm writing notes on a MUD I play. Lines can only be 79 characters long for each note, so it's a hassle sometimes to write a note unless you're counting characters. The code is below:

```
function wrap(str, limit, indent, indent1)
  indent = indent or ""
  indent1 = indent1 or indent
  limit = limit or 79
  local here = 1-#indent1
  return indent1..str:gsub("(%s+)()(%S+)()",
                          function(sp, st, word, fi)
                            if fi-here > limit then
                              here = st - #indent
                              return "\n"..indent..word
                            end
                          end)
end
```

This would work great; I can type a 300 character line and it will format it to 79 characters, respecting full words.

The problem I'm having, and I cannot seem to figure out how to solve, is that sometimes, I want to add colour codes to the line, and colour codes are not counted against word count. For example:

```
@GThis is a colour-coded @Yline that should @Bbreak off at 79 @Mcharacters, but ignore @Rthe colour codes (@G, @Y, @B, @M, @R, etc) when doing so.
```

Essentially, it would strip the colour codes away and break the line appropriately, but without losing the colour codes.

**Edited to include what it should check, and what the final output should be.**

The function would only check the string below for line breaks:

```
This is a colour-coded line that should break off at 79 characters, but ignore the colour codes (, , , , , etc) when doing so.
```

but would actually return:

```
@GThis is a colour-coded @Yline that should @Bbreak off at 79 @Ncharacters, but ignore 
the colour codes (@G, @Y, @B, @M, @R, etc) when doing so.
```

To complicate things, we also have xterm colour codes, which are similar, but look like this:

```
@x123
```

It is always @x followed by a 3-digit number. And lastly, to further complicate things, I don't want it to strip out purpose colour codes (which would be @@R, @@x123, etc.).

Is there a clean way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean by "ignore". Can you provide the output you expect for your example?

Comment: Can multiple colors be used inside the same word (such as `@RL@Gu@Ba`) ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, yes. I could have a different colour code for every letter if I wanted. `@x123L@Ru@x032a`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(sp, st, word, fi)
  local delta = 0
  word:gsub('@([@%a])', 
    function(c)
      if c == '@'     then delta = delta + 1 
      elseif c == 'x' then delta = delta + 5
      else                 delta = delta + 2 
      end
    end)
  here = here + delta
  if fi-here > limit then
    here = st - #indent + delta
    return "\n"..indent..word
  end
end
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. I edited the post because you had `if c = '@'` when it needed to be `if c == '@'`. Thanks for coming up with the solution neatly and quickly!

Comment: Appears my edit wasn't approved. At any rate, see previous comment for the edit change needed. Thanks again!