# Lua Carrying over a value through line wrap code

Tags: string, lua, match

Previously, I received help in the following link:

[Lua Line Wrapping excluding certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031473/lua-line-wrapping-excluding-certain-characters)

Short description of the above is that I was looking for a way to be able run a line wrap function while ignoring character count of certain characters.

Now I've come across another issue. I want to be able to carry the last colour code over to the new line. For example:

```
If this line @Rwere over 79 characters, I would want to @Breturn the last known colour code @Yon the line break.
```

Running the function I have in mind would result in:

```
If this line @Rwere over 79 characters, I would want to @Breturn the last known
@Bcolour code @Yon the line break.
```

instead of

```
If this line @Rwere over 79 characters, I would want to @Breturn the last known
colour code @Yon the line break.
```

I wish for it to do so because in many cases, the MUD will default back to the @w colour code, so it would make colourizing text rather difficult.

I've figured the easiest way to do that would be a reverse match, so I've written a reverse_text function:

```
function reverse_text(str)
  local text = {}
  for word in str:gmatch("[^%s]+") do
    table.insert(text, 1, word)
  end
  return table.concat(text, " ")
end
```

and it turns:

```
@GThis @Yis @Ba @Mtest.
```

to

```
@Mtest. @Ba @Yis @GThis
```

The issue I'm running into with creating the string.match is the fact that colour codes can be in one of two formats:

**@%a** or **@x%d%d%d**

Additionally, I don't want it to return a colour code that doesn't colour, which is indicated as:

**@@%a** or **@@x%d%d%d**

What's the best way to accomplish my end goal without compromising my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function wrap(str, limit, indent, indent1)
  indent = indent or ""
  indent1 = indent1 or indent
  limit = limit or 79
  local here = 1-#indent1
  local last_color = ''
  return indent1..str:gsub("(%s+)()(%S+)()",
    function(sp, st, word, fi)
      local delta = 0
      local color_before_current_word = last_color
      word:gsub('()@([@%a])', 
        function(pos, c)
          if c == '@' then 
            delta = delta + 1 
          elseif c == 'x' then 
            delta = delta + 5
            last_color = word:sub(pos, pos+4)
          else                 
            delta = delta + 2 
            last_color = word:sub(pos, pos+1)
          end
        end)
      here = here + delta
      if fi-here > limit then
        here = st - #indent + delta
        return "\n"..indent..color_before_current_word..word
      end
    end)
end
```

Comment: Once again, pure genius on this. Guess I was going about it the wrong way the entire time! Thanks again!